# Default to songs tab when presenting MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmediapickercontroller

When I present a `MPMediaPickerController` in `iOS7`, the default tab is the Playlists tab.
How do I change the default tab to the Songs tab?
I have searched everywhere and I cannot find a solution, but I know it is possible because I see that other apps have done this.

Here is how I'm presenting the media picker controller:

```
- (void)showPicker {
    MPMediaPickerController *mediapicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
    mediapicker.delegate = self;
    mediapicker.prompt = @"Select a song";
    [mediapicker setAllowsPickingMultipleItems:YES];
    [mediapicker setShowsCloudItems:YES];
    [self presentViewController:mediapicker animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the default tab of the `MPMediaPickerController`, prior to iOS 7 the defaults tab of the MPMediaPickerController was songs tab, but in ios 7 they have changed it to playlist tab!
The applications which you might have seen would have been running on ios 6 or less.

For more info you can check the [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) which doesn't mention anything like this.

Sorry, It's not a regular `UITabBarController`.

It's a guess but can you try following, it might work changing the init with Media Type to `MPMediaTypeMusic`!

```
MPMediaPickerController *picker =
[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];
```

Comment: The apps that do this are running on iOS 7, I just checked.

Comment: Then are you sure that it's MPMediaPickerController, because i have read the entire documentation, it no where touches upon setting the tabs programmatically.

Comment: It looks just like one, but I can't tell for sure. Here's an app that does it, for example https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-hd-free/id476555713?mt=8

Comment: I have verified with another app and they are using an MPMediaPickerController and the default tab is the songs tab.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are adding it as a controller? It will be helpful! may be i can help you with this

Comment: Just a guess `MPMediaPickerController *picker =
    [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];` Can you try this and let me know that it worked for you or not! Change the initWithMediaType!

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try using different initWithMediaTypes! If something will it'll be the initialize part! Try some diff values. Rest nothing can help you as if now.